# Is there a way to know how many processes are opening a file?

Tags: linux, files, processes

Is there a way to know how many processes are currently opening a file in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lsof can do this:

```
lsof <filename>
```

for example:

```
┌─[root@Fedora]─[~]─[02:39 pm]
└─[$]› lsof scripts/network_menu.sh
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
less      26419 root    4r   REG  253,1    67271 931810 scripts/network_menu.sh
network_m 26572 root  255r   REG  253,1    67271 931810 scripts/network_menu.sh
```

the first instance above is me running "less" on the file as root, the second is the script being run by root.

Answer (score 2):

Try with command `lsof /path/filename`

it will show you details for processes that are using the file.

Answer (score 2):

`lsof` will tell which which processes have the file(s) open at that point in time, but if you want to see how many processes open file(s) over a period of time, you can use `inotifywait` or `inotifywatch`.

inotifywait can be set in monitoring mode to continuously report events on the specified files:

`inotifywait -m -r /lib*`

inotifywatch can provide a summary of events over a time period:

`inotifywatch -t 10 -r /lib*`

Since you asked for processes opening files, you can add the `-e open` option to limit the output to only show OPEN events:

`inotifywait -e open -m -r /lib*`